# equivalent phrases: a sticker and have stickers

Tags: word-choice

(1) All four sides of the box have **a** sticker.

(2) All four sides of the box have sticker**s**.

Do both sentences mean each side has one sticker?

Comment: (1) would be better expressed as _Each of the four sides of the box has a sticker [on it]._

Answer (score 2):

No, the sentences do not necessarily have the same meaning. The second sentence (all four sides have sticker**s**) means each side has one *or more* stickers. It might be only one per side, or it might be hundreds.